# Multiple threads open in call-stack of vscode debugger

Tags: c++, gdb, visual-studio-code, callstack, vscode-debugger

[image]

As you can see in the call stack section, three threads are opened when there is no need for them? I think they are making the process slower. Can someone help me fix this please?
Thank you.

P.S.

Here is my c_cpp_properties.json file:

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Win32",
        "includePath": [
            "${workspaceFolder}/**",
            "C:\\MinGW\\lib\\gcc\\mingw32\\9.2.0\\include\\c++"
        ],
        "defines": [
            "_DEBUG",
            "UNICODE",
            "_UNICODE"
        ],
        "compilerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "cStandard": "c11",
        "cppStandard": "c++17",
        "intelliSenseMode": "gcc-x64"
    }
],
"version": 4
}
```

Here is my launch.json file:

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

And here is my tasks.json file:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "shell",
        "label": "C/C++: cpp.exe build active file",
        "command": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\g++.exe",
        "args": [
            "-g",
            "${file}",
            "-o",
            "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": "build"
    }
]
}
```

I am trying to get vscode working for the first time. I really liked the debugging features and the cool UI but this multiple thread opening everytime is making things difficult. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is what I stumbled over as well when doing C++ development in Visual Studio. There occur a variety of threads I don't know nor started explicitly in my code. I assume these threads are added by the system due to linking to the win32 API libs (or anything else) or by the start-up code generated by the compiler itself. I guess there is not much what you can do about this (except, maybe, linking against the single-threading runtime lib. instead). However, I wouldn't concern too much about this. I guess the performance penalty is negligible.

Comment: Hi there @Scheff , thank you for your advise. When you said "except, maybe, linking against the single-threading runtime lib. instead". How can I do this?

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure whether this is still an option - it was in the past. Furthermore, my knowledge is limited to Windows with MSVC. I don't know how this is done for g++. (It probably has it's own runtime lib.) However, FYI: [Description of the default C and C++ libraries that a program will link with when built by using Visual C++](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/154753/description-of-the-default-c-and-c-libraries-that-a-program-will-link)